# Fetching text value from SQL table to use in header: Location

Tags: php, sql

I want to fetch the landing_page value from this SQL table and add it to header location

: Ive got the following code at the top of the page but this is giving me a blank page:

```
 <?php  
     foreach($[user_name] as $user) {
    $location="Location:http://".$user['landing_page'];
    header($location);
 }
 ?>

<!-- if you need user information, just put them into the $_SESSION variable and output them here -->
Order: <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>. You are securely logged in.
```

Where am i going wrong?

[image]

[image]

The original code is a login script with me trying to make the user to go google.com once logged in

Comment: if your landing_page as http:// as shown in DB image why to add http:// in the header("Location ") :

Comment: A blank page usually means a PHP error. Turn on error reporting by adding `ini_set('display_errors', true);` at the start of your page. Also, `$user_name` seems like a strange name for that variable and the foreach looks wrong there too.

Answer (score 1):

You are not appending the variable properly. Try with,

```
header('"'.$user['landing_page'].'");
```

Comment: There already is a http:// in the database. This would result in `Location:http://http://blah.com`.

Comment: This still takes me to a blank page, not an URL error.

Comment: Why you are trying it in a foreach loop? If the query returns only one record everytime then don't use `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by Simply appending the argument in header

```
header("Location: " . $user['landing_page']);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
header("Location: ".$user['landing_page']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php  
     foreach($user_name as $user) {
        header("Location:http://".$user['landing_page']);
     }
 ?>
```

or

```
<?php  
     foreach($user_name as $user) {
        $location="Location:http://".$user['landing_page'];
        header($location);
     }
 ?>
```